# Use an Outlook Macro to Send Files by Email

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Attaching all files of a folder to a Microsoft outlook email using a macro code

```
Dim fldName As String
Sub SendFilesbuEmail()
    ' From slipstick.me/njpnx
    Dim sFName As String

    i = 0

    fldName = "C:\Users\"

    sFName = Dir(fldName)

    Do While Len(sFName) > 0
        Call SendasAttachment(sFName)
        sFName = Dir
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print fName
    Loop

    MsgBox i & " files were sent"
End Sub

Function SendasAttachment(fName As String)
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olMsg As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olAtt As Outlook.Attachments

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
    Set olAtt = olMsg.Attachments

    ' attach file
    olAtt.Add (fldName & fName)

    ' send message
    With olMsg
        .Subject = "Here's that file you wanted"
        .To = "abcde@gmail.com"
        .HTMLBody = "Hi " & olMsg.To & ", <br /><br /> I have attached " & fName & " as you requested."
        .Send
    End With
End Function
```

I am getting 0 files sent and the document is not getting transferred to Microsoft outlook in the email

Comment: Please edit your question after visiting this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Show us your code and be precise when telling us which part does not work.

Comment: and the next code is

Comment: I am getting 0 files sent and the document is not getting transferred to microsoft outlook in the email

Comment: Please sonaa, edit your answer and paste your code there with the right format so we can see your code in your question post.

Comment: Have you updated `fldName = "C:\Users\"` ? are trying to attached all the files into one email?

Comment: @Remi: can you please tell me what is wrong the code?

Comment: What issue are you having with code?

Comment: Hi ,I am getting 0 files sent

Comment: the files should be sent to "abc@gmail.com" but it is not achieved through my code

Comment: @Om: can you please provide some solution on the same

Comment: Where is your files located and do you want to attached all files in one email or one file per email?

Comment: @Om : I want to attach all the files in one email,my files are located in desktop

Answer (score 1):

*To Attached all files into one Email, try modifying your code.*

*Example.*

```
Option Explicit
Dim FilesPath As String
Sub SendFilesbuEmail()
    Dim File As String
    Dim i As Long

    FilesPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\"
    'FilesPath = "C:\Users\Om3r\Desktop\FolderName\"
    File = Dir(FilesPath)

    Call SendasAttachment(File)

End Sub

Function SendasAttachment(File As String)
    Dim olApp As Object ' Outlook.Application
    Dim olMsg As Object ' Outlook.MailItem
    Dim Atmts As Object ' Outlook.Attachments

    Dim i As Long

    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMsg = olApp.CreateItem(0) ' email
    Set Atmts = olMsg.Attachments
    i = 0

    ' send message
    With olMsg

        Do While Len(File) > 0
            Atmts.Add (FilesPath & File)
            File = Dir
            i = i + 1
        Loop
        .Display
        .Subject = "Here's that file you wanted"
        .To = "alias@domain.com"
        .HTMLBody = "Hi " & olMsg.To & ", <br /><br /> I hav attch Files"
    End With

    MsgBox i & " Files were sent"

    Set olMsg = Nothing
    Set Atmts = Nothing


End Function
```

*Make sure to update `FilesPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\FolderName\"` FolderName to the  correct folder name.*

*You can also use `FilesPath = "C:\Users\Om3r\Desktop\FolderName\"` and make sure to update Om3r and FolderName*

Comment: I am getting error in "Dim olApp As Outlook.Application" line ,the error is user defined type is not defined .

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Excel or Outlook?

Comment: Thanks for thr update,but file is not getting attached